# A command which produces index if optional argument is not empty

Tags: macros, conditionals, indexing

I would like to define a command which creates an index with a certain name, when i pass the name, and doesn't create any index if there is no name passed.

My first idea was to write it like that:

```
\newcommand{\kw}[1][]{\emph{#2}\index{#1}}
```

but the compiler gets stuch when I pass an empty optional argument. How can I build an if-then structure like the following?

```
\newcommand{\kw}[1][]{
 if(#1 is not empty)
  \emph{#2}\index{#1}}
 else
  \emph{#2}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use `xparse` (why not?), you can use some traditional tricks, for example:

```
\newcommand{\kw}[2][]{%
  \emph{#2}%
  \if&#1&\else
    \index{#1}%
  \fi
}
```

`xparse`'s `\IfValueT` is safer in some cases. A safer implementation without LaTeX3 is:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\kw}[2][]{%
  \emph{#2}%
  \ifstrempty{#1}{}{\index{#1}}%
}
```

Comment: Why the `{a}` in the second example? Shouldn't it be `{}`?

Comment: @cgnieder: Sorry, it's a typo.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`xparse`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) package from the LaTeX3 project.

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\kw{o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
    % #1 is empty.
  }{%
    % #1 has a value.
  }%
}
```

To recreate your example command:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\kw{om}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
    \emph{#2}%
  }{%
    \emph{#2}\index{#1}%
  }%
}
```

Comment: More simply, `\emph{#2}\IfValueT{#1}{\index{#1}}`. Be careful with spurious spaces; in your example macro you have three of them.

Comment: @egreg I wasn't aware that there is a `\IfValueT`; it's not mentioned in the `xparse` documentation.

Comment: Yes, it is, on page 7; note that the entry in the margin is `\IfValueTF` with T and F in italics and underlined in red. This means that `\IfValueT`, `\IfValueF` and `\IfValueTF` are available.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for pointing that out; I'd seen the underlining but didn't know what it meant.

Comment: I upvoted your answer and edited it in order it does what's advertised; I won't do the same next time.